# How can I optimise edge creation and vertex deletion in an Adjacency set representation of a graph?

Tags: c++, optimization, graph-theory

I have a graph represented with an Adjacency set similar to:

```cpp
struct Vertex {
    int x;
    bool operator==(const Vertex& b) {
        return x==b.x;
    }
};

template<> struct std::hash<Vertex> {
    std::size_t operator()(Vertex const& v) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>()(v.x);
    }
};


struct Edge {
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr;
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to;
    double weight;
    Edge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr_in, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to_in) : fr(fr_in), to(to_in) {};
};


class Graph{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> addVertex() {
        auto new_vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>();
        mAdjacencySet[new_vertex] = {};
        return new_vertex;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Edge> addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to) {
        auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>(fr, to);
        mAdjacencySet[fr][to] = edge;
        return edge;
    }
    void deleteVertex(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> v) {
        mAdjacencySet.erase(v);
        for (auto& [key, val] : mAdjacencySet) {
            val.erase(v);
        }
    };
private:
    std::unordered_map<
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
        std::unordered_map<
            std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
            std::shared_ptr<Edge>,
            Deref::Hash,
            Deref::Compare
        >,
        Deref::Hash,
        Deref::Compare
    > mAdjacencySet;
};
```

After I build my graph, I need to prune as many edges as possible because they are expensive to calculate.

One of the strategies to do so, is to delete any vertices with out degree of zero, EXCEPT for the destination vertex. This is very slow to do, relative to the rest of my program.

I wrote a script to time the relative parts of the complexity of each part:

```
int main() {
    Timer wholeProgram;
    wholeProgram.start();

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = g.addVertex();
    auto v2 = g.addVertex();
    auto e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    Timer makingVertices;
    makingVertices.start();
    size_t n = 1e3;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> vertices(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        vertices[i] = g.addVertex();
        vertices[i]->x = i;
    }
    makingVertices.stop();

    Timer makingEdges;
    makingEdges.start();
    for (auto v1 : vertices) {
        for (auto v2: vertices) {
            if (v1!=v2) {
                g.addEdge(v1, v2);
            }
        }
    }
    makingEdges.stop();

    Timer deletingVertices;
    deletingVertices.start();
    for (auto vert : vertices) {
        g.deleteVertex(vert);
    }
    deletingVertices.stop();

    wholeProgram.stop();

    std::cout << "Making Verts: " << makingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Making edges: " << makingEdges.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Deleting verts: " << deletingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Whole program: " << wholeProgram.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And the timings (with '-O3') are:

```
Making Verts: 0
Making edges: 270
Deleting verts: 188
Whole program: 458
```

(In my actual code base, the deleting of the vertices is actually around 90% of the time to create the graph).

How can I optimize this code to reduce the time to delete vertices (And also I guess optimize the creation of edges, as this is also slow)?

The full code to run this example is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Timer
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        m_StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = true;
    }
    
    void stop()
    {
        m_EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = false;
    }
    
    double elapsedMilliseconds()
    {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> endTime;
        
        if(m_bRunning)
        {
            endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
        else
        {
            endTime = m_EndTime;
        }
        
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - m_StartTime).count();
    }
    
    double elapsedSeconds()
    {
        return elapsedMilliseconds() / 1000.0;
    }
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_StartTime;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_EndTime;
    bool                                               m_bRunning = false;
};

struct Deref {
    /**
     * @brief Function to dereference the pointer when hashing elements in a hashmap of shared pointers
     * 
     */
    struct Hash {
        template <typename T> std::size_t operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& p) const
        {
            return std::hash<T>()(*p);
        }
        template <typename T> std::size_t operator()(T const & p) const
        {
            return std::hash<T>(p);
        }
    };
    /**
     * @brief Function to dereference the pointer when comparing elements in a hashmap of shared pointers
     * 
     */
    struct Compare {
        template <typename T> bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<T> const& b) const
        {
            return *a == *b;
        }
        template <typename T> bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const
        {
            return a == b;
        }
    };
};

struct Vertex {
    int x;
    bool operator==(const Vertex& b) {
        return x==b.x;
    }
};

template<> struct std::hash<Vertex> {
    std::size_t operator()(Vertex const& v) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>()(v.x);
    }
};


struct Edge {
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr;
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to;
    double weight;
    Edge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr_in, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to_in) : fr(fr_in), to(to_in) {};
};


class Graph{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> addVertex() {
        auto new_vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>();
        mAdjacencyList[new_vertex] = {};
        return new_vertex;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Edge> addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to) {
        auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>(fr, to);
        mAdjacencyList[fr][to] = edge;
        return edge;
    }
    void deleteVertex(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> v) {
        mAdjacencyList.erase(v);
        for (auto& [key, val] : mAdjacencyList) {
            val.erase(v);
        }
    };
private:
    std::unordered_map<
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
        std::unordered_map<
            std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
            std::shared_ptr<Edge>,
            Deref::Hash,
            Deref::Compare
        >,
        Deref::Hash,
        Deref::Compare
    > mAdjacencyList;
};

int main() {
    Timer wholeProgram;
    wholeProgram.start();

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = g.addVertex();
    auto v2 = g.addVertex();
    auto e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    Timer makingVertices;
    makingVertices.start();
    size_t n = 1e3;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> vertices(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        vertices[i] = g.addVertex();
        vertices[i]->x = i;
    }
    makingVertices.stop();

    Timer makingEdges;
    makingEdges.start();
    for (auto v1 : vertices) {
        for (auto v2: vertices) {
            if (v1!=v2) {
                g.addEdge(v1, v2);
            }
        }
    }
    makingEdges.stop();

    Timer deletingVertices;
    deletingVertices.start();
    for (auto vert : vertices) {
        g.deleteVertex(vert);
    }
    deletingVertices.stop();

    wholeProgram.stop();

    std::cout << "Making Verts: " << makingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Making edges: " << makingEdges.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Deleting verts: " << deletingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Whole program: " << wholeProgram.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And to run it, you can [view it online](https://godbolt.org/z/d7EWzxYjT)

Comment: Step 1: add a destructor and a copy constructor to `Edge`, Step 2: add a counter to `Vertex`, and have `Edge`'s constructor, destructor, and copy constructor increment and decrement the counter, Step 3: now you can prune `Vertex`es without any edge in `O(n)`.

Comment: perhaps a better question for the [code review exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This looks like a good question for Code Review, but please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The title of the question should probably be changed.

Comment: Your mAdjacencySet structure is horribly complex.  Remember KISS.  The usual way to do this is an adjacency matrix ( simplest ) or a vector of adjacent vertices for each vertex ( more complex but memory efficient for many vertices and few edges ).  If you care about performance you need to keep it simple.

Comment: @ravenspoint I have a lot more edges than vertices, What is a good data structure for this?

Comment: In that case an adjacency matrix is the way to go, since it will not waste lots of memory on unconnected vertices.

Comment: @ravenspoint My other problem is that I dont know ahead of building the graph, how many vertices I will have, so constantly resizing will be slow, no?

Comment: In C++ an adjacency matrix is best constructed using a vector of vectors, which can be extended as you go along.